# Python3 remove entire nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
{'result':{'result':[
         {
            'Company':{
               'PostAddress':None
            },
            'ExternalPartnerProperties':None,
            'Id':123456,
            'Level':'Level1',
            'Name':'Name1',
            'ParentId':456789,
            'State':'InTrial',
            'TrialExpirationTime':1435431669
         },
         {
            'Company':{
               'PostAddress':None
            },
            'ExternalPartnerProperties':None,
            'Id':575155,
            'Level':'Level2',
            'Name':'Name2',
            'ParentId':456789,
            'State':'InTrial',
            'TrialExpirationTime':1491590226
         },
         {
            'Company':{
               'PostAddress':None
            },
            'ExternalPartnerProperties':None,
            'Id':888888,
            'Level':'Level2',
            'Name':'Name3',
            'ParentId':456789,
            'State':'InProduction',
            'TrialExpirationTime':1493280310
         },
```

My code:

```
for i in partner_output['result']['result']:
    if "InProduction" in i['State']:
        del i['Company'], i['ExternalPartnerProperties'], i['Id'], i['Level'], i['Name'], i['ParentId'], i['State'], i['TrialExpirationTime']
```

If I do this, then I return the following result

```
{'result': {'result': [{
            'Company':{
               'PostAddress':None
            },
            'ExternalPartnerProperties':None,
            'Id':123456,
            'Level':'Level1',
            'Name':'Name1',
            'ParentId':456789,
            'State':'InTrial',
            'TrialExpirationTime':1435431669
         },
         {
            'Company':{
               'PostAddress':None
            },
            'ExternalPartnerProperties':None,
            'Id':575155,
            'Level':'Level2',
            'Name':'Name2',
            'ParentId':456789,
            'State':'InTrial',
            'TrialExpirationTime':1491590226
         },
         {},
```

but the total number of items is still 3 ... the 3rd container is just empty, but still a container. How can I delete the 3rd container all together?

I cannot use:

```
for i in partner_output['result']['result']:
    if "InProduction" in i['State']:
        del partner_output['result'][i]
```

because I get the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

So I don't know what to do now :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to replace the whole list, *keeping* the other items:

```
partner_output['result']['result'] = [
    i for i in partner_output['result']['result']
    if i['State'] != "InProduction"
]
```

Note that the test for the filter has been reversed; you want to keep all items that do not have `'State'` set to `InProduction`. Alternatively, keep values where the state is set to `InTrial`:

```
partner_output['result']['result'] = [
    i for i in partner_output['result']['result']
    if i['State'] == "InTrial"
]
```

Your second attempt failed because you tried to use `i`, a reference to a dictionary, as a key in the *outer* `partner_output['result']` dictionary. If you wanted to delete something from the `partner_output['result']['result']` list, you'd have to use the integer index (`del partner_output['result']['result'][2]`), but you can't do that in a loop because that has [consequences for the `for` loop progress across the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list).

Comment: Thank you! I simply wrote it to only include items with 'InTrial' in i['State'] -- awesome job, thank you.

Comment: @Ecaz: sure, just change the test to `'i['State'] == "InTrial"` then.